# How to get array element containing '/' in the string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array which I have split based on the white space. Now, as per my requirements, I have to get the array element which contains '/' in its contents, but I am not able to get it. I don't understand how to achieve it.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
 string[] arrdate = currentLine.Split(' ');
```

How do I get the array element consisting of a `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string s in arrdate)
{
   if (s.contains("/"))
   {
       //do something with s like add it to an array or if you only look for one string assign it and break out of the loop.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 string[] arrdate = currentLine.Split(' ');
 var dateItems = arrdate.Where(item => item.Contains("/")).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get only one item then try this

```
// split on the basis of white space
string[] arrdate = currentLine.Split(' ');

// now find out element with '/' using lambda
string item = arrdate.Where(item => item.Contains("/")).FirstOrDefault();

// if you don't want to use lambda then try for loop
string item;
for(int i = 0; i < arrdate.Length; i++)
{
if(arrdate[i].Contains("/"))
{
item = arrdate[i]
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// split on the basis of white space
string[] arrdate = currentLine.Split(' ');

// now find out element with '/' using lambda
string item = arrdate.Where(item => item.Contains("/")).FirstOrDefault();

// if you don't want to use lambda then try for loop
string item;
for(int i = 0; i < arrdate.Length; i++)
{
if(arrdate[i].Contains("/"))
{
item = arrdate[i]
}
}
```

Comment: Lol,  did you really just copy paste an answer from somebody else?